# Data cannot store in MongoDB

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am new to MongoDB, and I am trying to make a blog project using MongoDB and Node.js. I am having a problem as my data cannot be stored in MongoDB. I use the body-parser method to get the data, but the data is not stored in MongoDB. A little help would be nice, thank you.

```
const express=require('express')
const path=require('path')

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const BlogPost = require('./models/BlogPost.js')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database',{useNewUrlParser:true})

const app=new express()
const ejs=require('ejs')
app.set('view engine','ejs')

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.listen(4000,()=>{
    console.log('App listening on port 4000')
})

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index')
})

app.get('/about',(req,res)=>{
    //res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'pages/about.ejs')
    res.render('about')
})

app.get('/contact',(req,res)=>{
   // res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'pages/contact.ejs'))
   res.render('contact')
})


app.get('/post',(req,res)=>{
   //res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'pages/post.ejs'))
   res.render('post')
})

app.get('/posts/new',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('create')
})

app.post('/posts/store',(req,res)=>{
    BlogPost.create(req.body,(error,blogpost)=>{
      
    res.redirect('/')  
    })

})
```

This is my code in create.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <%- include('layouts/header'); %>

  
    <body>

        <!-- Navigation-->
        <%- include('layouts/navbar'); -%>
        
        <!-- Page Header-->
        <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('/assets/img/contact-bg.jpg')">
            <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <div class="page-heading">
                            <h1>Create New Post</h1>
                            <span class="subheading">Have questions? I have answers.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Main Content-->
        <main class="mb-4">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <form action="/posts/store" method="POST"></form>
                        <p>Want to get in touch? Fill out the form below to send me a message and I will get back to you as soon as possible!</p>
                        <div class="my-5">
                            <!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *-->
                            <!-- * * SB Forms Contact Form * *-->
                            <!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *-->
                            <!-- This form is pre-integrated with SB Forms.-->
                            <!-- To make this form functional, sign up at-->
                            <!-- https://startbootstrap.com/solution/contact-forms-->
                            <!-- to get an API token!-->
                            <form id="contactForm" data-sb-form-api-token="API_TOKEN">
                                <div class="form-floating">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="title"  placeholder="title" type="text" name="title" />
                                    <label for="title">title</label> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="body"  placeholder="body" name="body"></textarea>
                                    <label for="body">body</label>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <!-- Submit success message-->
                                <!---->
                                <!-- This is what your users will see when the form-->
                                <!-- has successfully submitted-->
                                <div class="d-none" id="submitSuccessMessage">
                                    <div class="text-center mb-3">
                                        <div class="fw-bolder">Form submission successful!</div>
                                        To activate this form, sign up at
                                        <br />
                                        <a href="https://startbootstrap.com/solution/contact-forms">https://startbootstrap.com/solution/contact-forms</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Submit error message-->
                                <!---->
                                <!-- This is what your users will see when there is-->
                                <!-- an error submitting the form-->
                                <div class="d-none" id="submitErrorMessage"><div class="text-center text-danger mb-3">Error sending message!</div></div>
                                <!-- Submit Button-->
                                <button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase " id="submitButton" type="submit">Send</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    

    <%- include('layouts/footer'); -%>
    <%- include('layouts/scripts'); -%>   

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you don't even need to use bodyparsar you can use instead "express" like this - 
`express.json()`, `express.urlencoded({extended:true})`

Comment: Is connection url of mongodb is correct ? What kind of error you are getting ?

Comment: It not show error like the code is wrong..But it is not working when I try to submit information in my blog, the Mongodb did not store the information.

Comment: I try to change from body-parser to express but it seem it still cannot store the info

Comment: are you successfully connecting to mongodb ?

Comment: can you change `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database')` to `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database')` and let me know if helps

Comment: connection url of mongodb is not wrong as before I can connect with it

Comment: I already tried it..but it still not working